# How to use pyspark to convert row array into multiple columns?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've raw data like this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| "A:1, B:2, C:3" | XXX |

The result I want is like this:

| Column A | A | B | C | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "A:1, B:2, C:3" | 1 | 2 | 3 | XXX |

Can anyone help with pyspark code?

Comment: Will you always have the same amount of new columns (in this case A,B,C) or is the amount of such columns variable?

Comment: yes, always the same amount, in thise case A ,  B, C, won't have D, it is fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
df =spark.createDataFrame([
(78,'"A:1, B:2, C:3"'),
],
('id',  'ColumnA'))
```

Replace the `"` with nothing. Split the resulting string with `,` and this will give you a list. Iterate the list elements converting them to lists by splitting with `:` and make all those lists of `StructType`. Explode the list. group by `columnA` and pivot. Code below

```
df.withColumn('ColumnA', split(translate(col('ColumnA'),'"',''),',')).withColumn('ColumnA_edited', explode(transform('ColumnA', lambda x: struct(*[split(x,':')[i].alias(f'x{i+1}') for i in range(2)])))).select( 'ColumnA','ColumnA_edited.*').groupby('ColumnA').pivot('x1').agg(first('x2')).show()


+-----------------+---+---+---+
|          ColumnA|  B|  C|  A|
+-----------------+---+---+---+
|[A:1,  B:2,  C:3]|  2|  3|  1|
+-----------------+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but if I still have "column B", "column C“,etc, which I also hope to retain, it seems I only can reserve ”column A“ after **groupby** function.

Comment: If it helped upvote by pressing upper arrow on the left and accept by clicking the tick

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution possible thanks to the fixed amount of columns:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# create an array column from string
df = df.withColumn('array', F.split('Column A', ', '))

# create a list with the new column names and the expressions to calculate them
new_cols = [F.regexp_replace(df.array[i], c+':', '').alias(c) for i, c in zip([0, 1, 2], ['A', 'B', 'C'])]

# select the chosen columns
df.select('Column A', *new_cols, 'Column B').show()

+-------------+---+---+---+--------+
|     Column A|  A|  B|  C|Column B|
+-------------+---+---+---+--------+
|A:1, B:2, C:3|  1|  2|  3|     XXX|
+-------------+---+---+---+--------+
```